# Android SQLite Syntax - IN clause and Subselect

Tags: android, sqlite, subquery, clause, where-in

i spend a lot of time of searching a resolution for this query in android.

```
SELECT * FROM positionen WHERE _id IN (SELECT positionenid  FROM fahrtenbuch_position WHERE fahrtenbuchid = 2)
```

i think im on the wrong way. there are no subselects in android neither in the rawQuerys nor on the normal querys ? can anyone push me in some direction please ? how do i obtain the _id with some other id's?

Comment: It must to work. Are you sure that _id is really in the subselect clause?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played much with android's sqllite, but I have a feeling this may work for you. instead of :

```
SELECT * FROM positionen WHERE _id IN (SELECT positionenid  FROM fahrtenbuch_position WHERE fahrtenbuchid = 2)
```

try

```
SELECT * FROM positionen p inner join fahrtenbuch_position f on p._id=f.fahrtenbuch_position where fahrtenbuchid = 2
```

If you're curious about what I just did, read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_join#Inner_join

Comment: yeah it works! :D i tryed inner join before but i had an error. but why does the other one not work ? that one with the "IN".

Comment: I have no idea why the sub-select (the one with the "in") doesn't work - I don't know a lot about the specifics of the android sqllite database, but the inner join is supposed to be more efficient